# Why my webjob is failing when I am adding reference to class library project?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-triggered

I have console application and a class library build on **Target Framework**: `.NET Framework 4.8`. The class library implements the database operations. The programs runs fine locally but not when console application is published on app service using `publish azure webjob`. The error message is:

```
[06/24/2022 17:36:29 > fa1ef8: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[06/24/2022 17:36:34 > fa1ef8: SYS INFO] Run script 'WinSCP.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[06/24/2022 17:36:34 > fa1ef8: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[06/24/2022 17:36:43 > fa1ef8: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[06/24/2022 17:36:43 > fa1ef8: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -1073740771
```

But when i am removing the reference of my class library and commenting the referenced code then it works fine.

This is the app.config of my class library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8984c91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
<appSettings>
  <add key="EhrApiBaseUrl" value="http://something/api/" />
  <add key="EhrUsername" value="xyz@xyz.com" />
  <add key="EhrPassword" value="xyz" />
  <add key="FCMServerKey" value="xyz" />
  <add key="FCMSenderId" value="xyz" />
  <add key="App" value="web" />  
</appSettings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis" publicKeyToken="4b01db77ab" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.40.0.0" newVersion="1.40.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis.Auth" publicKeyToken="4b0134db77ab" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.40.0.0" newVersion="1.40.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" publicKeyToken="cc7b11" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.1" newVersion="4.2.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.6.0" newVersion="4.0.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b12ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.1" newVersion="4.0.1.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b1ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Encodings.Web" publicKeyToken="cc7bddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.5.1" newVersion="4.0.5.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7dd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" publicKeyToken="cc7b12ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Json" publicKeyToken="cc7b1d2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.2" newVersion="4.0.1.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Identity.Client" publicKeyToken="0a619e8ae" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.30.1.0" newVersion="4.30.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Azure.Core" publicKeyToken="9272e44c8" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.23.0.0" newVersion="1.23.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Azure.Storage.Common" publicKeyToken="9274244c8" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.10.0.0" newVersion="12.10.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" /></startup><system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="IInnovaServicebinding" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://1.1.1.1/xyz/xyz.dll/xyz/xyz" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="IInnovaServicebinding" contract="InnovaService.IInnovaService" name="IInnovaServicePort" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Can you please suggest me how should I deal with this error when no log is being created in Azure Storage because the program is failing before start.

Answer (score 0):

I have create a webjob with add class library reference and its work fine as accepted.  Check below code and output.

Console application Target Framework .Net Framework 4.8 and also 4.8 for class library.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ClassLibrary2;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Application Start");
            Class1 class1 = new Class1();
            foreach(var val in class1.list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(val.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Add value in list");
            for(int i= 6;i < 10; i++){
                class1.list.Add(i );
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Add value in Database Table " + (i));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Print value after add value in Database Table");
            foreach (var val in class1.list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(val.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

```
[07/04/2022 10:01:12 > ec2b20: INFO] Application Start
[07/04/2022 10:01:12 > ec2b20: INFO] 1
[07/04/2022 10:01:12 > ec2b20: INFO] 2
[07/04/2022 10:01:12 > ec2b20: INFO] 3
[07/04/2022 10:01:12 > ec2b20: INFO] 4
[07/04/2022 10:01:12 > ec2b20: INFO] 5
[07/04/2022 10:01:12 > ec2b20: INFO] Add value in list
[07/04/2022 10:01:13 > ec2b20: INFO] Add value in Database Table 6
[07/04/2022 10:01:14 > ec2b20: INFO] Add value in Database Table 7
[07/04/2022 10:01:15 > ec2b20: INFO] Add value in Database Table 8
[07/04/2022 10:01:16 > ec2b20: INFO] Add value in Database Table 9
[07/04/2022 10:01:16 > ec2b20: INFO] Print value after add value in Database Table
[07/04/2022 10:01:16 > ec2b20: INFO] 1
[07/04/2022 10:01:16 > ec2b20: INFO] 2
[07/04/2022 10:01:16 > ec2b20: INFO] 3
[07/04/2022 10:01:16 > ec2b20: INFO] 4
[07/04/2022 10:01:16 > ec2b20: INFO] 5
[07/04/2022 10:01:16 > ec2b20: INFO] 6
[07/04/2022 10:01:16 > ec2b20: INFO] 7
[07/04/2022 10:01:16 > ec2b20: INFO] 8
[07/04/2022 10:01:16 > ec2b20: INFO] 9
```

your application cannot start due to problem while loading some .net assemblies. you can check all assemblies load properly.